# Pack and pass variadic template args to another template class

Tags: c++, templates, c++17, variadic-templates

This code snippet implements two classes - A command handler that takes in a command name and a list of supported sub-commands and a Meta class that holds all such supported "Commands".

I'm looking for a way to initialized these top level `CommandHandler` objects (`cmd_one_`, `cmd_two_`) together, instead of initializing the individual objects, say like this:

```
MetaCommandWrapper<COMMAND_ONE,
                <cmd_one::SUBCMD_ONE,
                 cmd_one::SUBCMD_TWO
                >,
            COMMAND_TWO,
                <cmd_two::SUBCMD_ONE,
                 cmd_two::SUBCMD_TWO
                >
           > meta_commands_;
```

That would make it easier to loop through supported commands in `MetaCommands` and call the appropriate `CommandHandler` class's method. For example, a method `execute` issued like this: `m.execute(COMMAND_ONE, cmd_one::SUBCMD_TWO)` would execute command one's second subcommand, and so on.

How do I go about doing that?

```
#include <cstdint>

enum meta_commands
{
    COMMAND_ONE,
    COMMAND_TWO
};

namespace cmd_one
{
enum subcmd
{
    SUBCMD_ONE,
    SUBCMD_TWO
};
}

namespace cmd_two
{
enum subcmd
{
    SUBCMD_ONE,
    SUBCMD_TWO
};
}

template <uint32_t Command, uint32_t...SubCommands>
class CommandHandler
{
};

class MetaCommands
{
private:
    CommandHandler<meta_commands::COMMAND_ONE, cmd_one::SUBCMD_ONE, cmd_one::SUBCMD_TWO> cmd_one_;
    CommandHandler<meta_commands::COMMAND_TWO, cmd_two::SUBCMD_ONE, cmd_two::SUBCMD_TWO> cmd_two_;
};

int main()
{
    MetaCommands m;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: "call the appropriate class's method" What method? Why do you need to iterate over them? Its unclear what problem you're trying to solve here.

Comment: Edited the question, hope it makes more sense now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure exactly what you need but it seems like `MetaCommands` should be a class template since you want to create it with different template parameters:

```cpp
template <class... CmdHandlers>
class MetaCommands {};
```

This would then not let you create an instance exactly as you asked for, but it'll be pretty similar:

```cpp
int main() {
    MetaCommands<
        CommandHandler<COMMAND_ONE, cmd_one::SUBCMD_ONE, cmd_one::SUBCMD_TWO>,
        CommandHandler<COMMAND_TWO, cmd_two::SUBCMD_ONE, cmd_two::SUBCMD_TWO> 
    > meta_commands_;
}
```

You could then extract or fold over the template arguments as you wish. Say you add a function for printing the `Command` and `SubCommand`s of a `CommandHandler`

```cpp
template <uint32_t Command, uint32_t... SubCommands>
class CommandHandler {
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const CommandHandler&) {
        os << "Cmd: " << Command << " Subs:";
        (..., (os << ' ' << SubCommands));
        return os;
    }
};
```

and add the same to `MetaCommands`:

```cpp
template <class... CmdHandlers>
class MetaCommands {
private:
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const MetaCommands&) {
        (..., (os << CmdHandlers{} << '\n'));
        return os;
    }
};
```

You'd be able to print it in `main` like so:

```cpp
int main() {
    MetaCommands<
        CommandHandler<COMMAND_ONE, cmd_one::SUBCMD_ONE, cmd_one::SUBCMD_TWO>,
        CommandHandler<COMMAND_TWO, cmd_two::SUBCMD_ONE, cmd_two::SUBCMD_TWO> 
    > meta_commands_;

    std::cout << meta_commands_ << '\n';
}
```

Output:

```
Cmd: 0 Subs: 0 1
Cmd: 1 Subs: 0 1
```

Comment: Sorry I wasnt able to frame my question clearly. But I think you got the essence of my question. Making `MetaCommands` a template that accepts variadic args (of CommandHandler class) is definitely something I should have thought of. I ideally want to create a "map" inside  `MetaCommands` so that a method `execute` of `MetaCommands` can take a command and a subcommand, use "command" to find the appropriate `CommandHandler` class and then pass the "subcommand" arg to that CommandHandler. Question would be how to create this "map" so as to route the subcommand to the appropriate `CommandHandler`

Comment: @rookie _"...can take a command and a subcommand..."_ - Ok, and these are runtime parameters then? Like [this](https://godbolt.org/z/hG7f5q5q3)? Or are they always known at compiletime?